# error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a async function with a fetch call to an api , in Safari the function works fine with no errors, but in Chrome and Firefox I get the following error:

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

I think it has something to do with the json response not being readable, but I was not sure how to fix this inside of the following function :

```
async function getUserTracks() {
    try {
      await fetch("https://www.soundpro.city/music/music_all/?format=json") 
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          for (item of data)
            trackNames.push(item['title']),
            trackUrl.push(item['track']),
            albums.push(item['artist_name'])
        })
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
}
getUserTracks();
console.log(trackNames, trackUrl, albums);
```

Comment: That URL is dead when I try to open it. Also CORS probably blocks it. With your edit, the URL now opens but definitely is not returning JSON.

Comment: mistyped the url try again

Comment: Your URL is not returning valid JSON. You can enclose this in a try/catch and catch the SyntaxError exception if the JSON is not valid.

Comment: the api is password protected, but the api is fine as i mentioned this works fine in safari it's only in firefox and chrome that i'm getting this error